# Ionic IonDatetime не удается задать разные цвета для placeholder и введенного значения

Tags: css, ionic

color перезаписывает значение --placeholder-color. Но по умолчанию color для введенного значения светлочерный.

Необходимо чтобы цвет для placeholder был сероватым а цвет введенного значения был чисто черный

Когда я использую следующий код, placeholder имеет цвет AAAAAA, а введенное значение светло черного цвета (по умолчанию)

```
.inputDate {
--placeholder-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

когда я использую следующий код, тогда заполнитель имеет черный цвет а должен иметь цвет AAAAAA

```
.inputDate {
color black;
--placeholder-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте эти варианты.

```css
/*Вариант 1*/

.inputDate {
    @include placeholder {
       color: #AAAAAA;
    }
}

/*Вариант 2*/

.inputDate::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.inputDate:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;;
}

.inputDate::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: на первый вариант ругается SassError: no mixin named placeholder
остальное не работает

Comment: @LORD, можете поместить свой код в песочницу и дать ссылку?